# How to install offline package from puppet manifest

Tags: puppet

```
class shell_ubn {
    file {
      "/home/shellinabox/shellinabox_2.14-1_amd64.deb":
        ensure => present,
        mode => 0777,
        source => "puppet:///modules/shell_ubn/shellinabox_2.14-1_amd64.deb",
        notify => Package["Shellinabox"],
    }

    package {
      "Shellinabox":
        ensure => installed,
        source => "/home/shellinabox/shellinabox_2.14-1_amd64.deb",
        require => File["/home/shellinabox/shellinabox_2.14-1_amd64.deb"],
    }
}
```

I have to install this package on my Ubuntu client but it gives this error:

```
Error: /Stage[main]/Shell_ubn/Package[Shellinabox]/ensure: change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install Shellinabox' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package Shellinabox
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `provider => 'dpkg'` parameter to your `package` resource.

Comment: still i getting the error is :->
Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: You cannot install dpkg packages without a source at 20:/etc/puppet/modules/shell_ubn/manifests/init.pp
Error: Could not set 'present' on ensure: You cannot install dpkg packages without a source at 20:/etc/puppet/modules/shell_ubn/manifests/init.pp
Wrapped exception:
You cannot install dpkg packages without a source

Comment: This makes no sense. According to your paste, the `package` does specify a source. Please update your question or ask a new one if things have changed.